# compute.networks.get to create GCP Instance group from a Shared VPC service project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP with Shared VPC and a host project and a service project:

I configured a Shared VPC host project and shared a VPC and subnets to a Service project and an user (**compute network User Role**).

If I create a VM usign a subnet from the host project I can do it without any problem but when I try creating an instance group from the service project I receive the following error:

Required 'compute.networks.get' permission for 'projects/[HOST PROJECT ID]/global/networks/vpc-host-network'

The only solution I could find was to assign the the **Compute network viewer** role to the service project user for whole HOST project.

Trying to assign the **compute network User Role** to the Compute engine service account in the service project didn't help and looks to me GCP documentation doesn't mention this.

Do you know if this is something expected and is it documented anywhere?

Thanks

EDIT: 
Please note that this is relevant only for ***unmanaged*** instance groups, for ***managed instance groups*** instead is working without problems.

Worth to mention that for ***managed*** instance groups in service projects, is necessary to have the *Google APIs Service Agent* ([PROJECT NUMBER]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com) account from the service project as a *compute network user account* in the HOST project for the necessary subnets

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a related to this one:

> With shared VPC, you need to allow users/serviceAccounts in the service project to use the sub-network with a google_compute_subnetwork_iam_binding resource using roles/compute.networkUser role.

see: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/1711

Comment: Unfortunately I have added all the service accounts from the service project as Compute network users for the subnets but it didn't work.

Comment: how about the permissions in the service project mentioned later in that post https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/1711#issuecomment-420484808?

Comment: Yes, I gave all service project's service accounts the "compute network user" for the shared subnets but with no luck. As I wrote also in the main body of the question, this seems to affect only "unmanaged" instance groups, instead "managed" instance groups are working as expected